# Atlas - Adding point coordinate icon

Tags: qgis, coordinates, filter, atlas

I have created an atlas for all countries in the world, and I would like to drop a pin to show the centre of the country (as attached). Is there a way to add these coordinates automatically such as in the picture below?[image: China map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the centroid of a country may be placed outside it's borders (e.g. with Japan), the tool `pole of inaccessibility` from the toolbox gives you a point within the borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a centroid on each polygons in QGIS. Vector > Geometry tools > Centroids